# How can I make one of the child linear layout in ListView's row not highlighted when being clicked

Tags: android

I use the following layout for my ListView row custom view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:duplicateParentState="false"
        android:clickable="false"    
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <!-- A lot of text views -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"     
        android:minHeight="48dp" >
        <!-- A lot of text views -->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

By using `android:duplicateParentState="false"` and `android:clickable="false"`, I'm expecting the `header` LinearLayout will not be highlighted when the listview row is being clicked.

However, it is still being highlighted. May I know how can I make the `header` LinearLayout not highlighted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to remove the visual highlight is to change `header`'s background drawable to a `StateListDrawable` which has the same drawable (e.g. a solid color) for all relevant states such as `state_pressed` and none.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your header view to new xml. Then in your activity/fragment inflate this view and call `addHeaderView(view, null, false);` on it (the third param is boolean isSelectable).

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null,false); 
getListView().addHeaderView(view, null, false);
```

Comment: That is not header view. Although its id is named "header", it can appear in several rows within a single list view.

Comment: Aha, sorry, I read it wrong. Have you tried the solution suggested by @laalto? That should work.